# Is writing enough to detect a connection loss?

Tags: java, sockets, netty, tcp

I'm using Java and Netty to connect to a Unity-Client through a TCP/IP connection.

Sometimes the connection can break and the Unity-guy proposed to send a ping (just a one byte message) every 5 seconds and if the time of reception of the last ping is higher than 30 seconds, the connection is lost.

Do I really need to mesure the time? Isn't it enough to trigger an exception if I try to send something through the socket? Is there a case where a write won't detect a connection loss?

I tagged it Netty since I am using it, but it probably is the same with a simple Socket connection.

Comment: No it isn't enough. TCP has buffering at both ends, which means that any specific write won't fail at all: it is the subsequent writes that will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real answer is: you have to define for yourself how you want your application to behave.

What I mean is: there are many different problems that could occur to your connection. Writing data, and failing immediately when that doesn't work is just *one* option to handle that.

You can also envision continuous pinging; for example to detect when the other is just "temporarily" unavailable. In other words: you establish some sort of "heartbeat" monitoring; and thus you enable your application for a "wider range" of potential "reactions".